# 1C Битрикс. Вывод всех элементов с сортировкой по дате создания с использованием компонента bitrix:news.list

Tags: php, битрикс

Извините за глупый вопрос. Помогите разобраться. Есть сайт на 1С Битрикс слайдер, который выводит новости. Слайдер работает на компоненте bitrix:news.list. В слайдере присутствуют разделы которые выводят новости в зависимости от определённого свойства информационного элемента. Тип свойства список. Необходимо по умолчанию выводить все элементы, не зависимо от присвоенного им свойства информационного элемента.

В настоящий момент элементы по умолчанию выводятся, но не все. Необходимо вывести все элементы с сортировкой по дате создания элемента или начала активности. Не понимаю, как подступиться..

Ниже привожу код шаблона компонента  bitrix:news.list

```
<?php

if (!defined('B_PROLOG_INCLUDED') || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED !== true) {
    die();
}
?>
<div class="container" data-role="tabs">
    <div class="tabs-selector" data-action="tabs-selector">
        <? foreach ($arResult['EVENT_NAMES'] as $eventIndex => $eventName): ?>
            <a href="#event_tab_<?= $eventIndex ?>" class="btn btn-border<?= $eventIndex == 0 ? ' is-selected' : '' ?>"><?=$eventName?></a>
        <? endforeach ?>
    </div>
    <div class="tabs-content" data-role="tab-container">
    <? foreach ($arResult['EVENT_NAMES'] as $eventIndex => $eventName): ?>
        <div data-role="tab-content" id="event_tab_<?= $eventIndex ?>"<?= $eventIndex == 0 ? ' class="is-visible"' : '' ?>>
            <div class="news-slider tab-slider"  data-slick='{"responsive": [{"breakpoint": "991", "settings": {"slidesToShow": 3}},{"breakpoint": "768", "settings": {"slidesToShow": 2}}, {"breakpoint": 0, "settings": "unslick"}]}'>
                <? foreach ($arResult['ITEMS'][$eventName] as $k => $arItem): ?>
                    <div class="news-item<? if ($k > 4):?>  d-none d-sm-block<? endif;?>">
                        <a href="<?=$arItem['URL'] ?>">
                            <figure><img src="<?=$arItem['IMG']['src']?>" alt="<?=$arItem['NAME'] ?>"></figure>
                            <b><?=$arItem['NAME'];?></b>
                            <p><?=$arItem['TEXT'];?></p>
                            <span>Подробнее</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                <? endforeach ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <? endforeach ?>
    </div>
</section>
```

Код файла "result_modifier.php"

```
<?php

if (!defined('B_PROLOG_INCLUDED') || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED !== true) {
    die();
}

define(DEFAULT_EVENT_NAME, 'Все новости');
define(DEFAULT_EVENT_ID, 0);
define(EVENT_ELEMENTS_MAX, 16);

$itemsData = [];
$arEventNames[] = DEFAULT_EVENT_NAME;
$arResult['EVENT_IDS'][DEFAULT_EVENT_NAME] = DEFAULT_EVENT_ID;
$arEventSorts = [
    DEFAULT_EVENT_NAME => 0,
];

foreach ($arResult['ITEMS'] as $arItem) {
    $eventName = $arItem['PROPERTIES']['EVENTS']['VALUE'] ? $arItem['PROPERTIES']['EVENTS']['VALUE'] : DEFAULT_EVENT_NAME;

    if (count($itemsData[$eventName]) < EVENT_ELEMENTS_MAX) {
        $itemsData[$eventName][] = [
            'NAME' => $arItem['NAME'],
            'URL'  => $arItem['DETAIL_PAGE_URL'],
            'IMG'  => CFile::ResizeImageGet($arItem['PREVIEW_PICTURE'], array('width'=>600, 'height'=>420), BX_RESIZE_IMAGE_EXACT, false),
            'TEXT' => $arItem['PREVIEW_TEXT']
        ];
    }
    if (!in_array($eventName, $arEventNames)) {
        $arEventNames[] = $eventName;
        $arResult['EVENT_IDS'][$eventName] = $arItem['PROPERTIES']['EVENTS']['VALUE_ENUM_ID'];
        $arEventSorts[$eventName] = $arItem['PROPERTIES']['EVENTS']['VALUE_SORT'];
    }
}

asort($arEventSorts);
$arResult['EVENT_NAMES'] = eventsResort($arEventNames, $arEventSorts);
$arResult['ITEMS'] = $itemsData;

/**
 * пересортировка групп новостей
 *
 * @param array $arEvents
 * @param array $arSorts
 *
 * @return array
 */
function eventsResort($arEvents = [], $arSorts = [])
{
    $arNew = [];
    foreach ($arSorts as $event => $sort) {
        foreach ($arEvents as $eventKey => $eventName) {
            if ($eventName == $event) {
                $arNew[] = $eventName;
                unset($arEvents[$eventKey]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    $arEvents = array_merge($arNew, $arEvents);
    $arEvents = array_values($arEvents);

    return $arEvents;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В настройках вызова компонента есть параметр FILTER_NAME
https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/components/content/articles_and_news/news_list.php
Вы можете ему передать свои значения фильтрации
https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/getlist.php

```
<?
global $arrFilter;
$arrFilter = array(/*параметры для фильтрации*/);
?>
```

Comment: изменение сортировки и результирующего массива компонента у вас происходит в файле "result_modifier.php". Как это всё выглядит на сайте? Приложите скриншот, не очень сейчас понятно о чём речь, нет наглядности.

Comment: спасибо за внимание к моей проблеме. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LycDJFqzca78Cz22iwj-nK9QDI-Lna4K/view?usp=sharing - скриншот того, как выглядит компонент. Во вкладке новости должны быть новости со всех остальных разделов.

Comment: define(EVENT_ELEMENTS_MAX, 16); тут значение не пробовали менять? Сколько элементов в инфоблоке слайдера? Посмотрите какие ограничения на количество стоят в настройках компонента bitrix:news.list

Comment: define(EVENT_ELEMENTS_MAX, 16); - управляет количеством элементов в слайдере. В каждом табе 16 элементов. Элементов на странице - 9999

Comment: если возможно, напишите мне vik.jerr@gmail.com